# How to redirect the output to two different files when two command are involved simultaneously?

Tags: unix, perf

I am using `perf` tool to analyze sort utility . I gave following command.

```
perf stat -x, ../bin/sort data >/dev/null 2>perf_data
```

I want to redirect the output of sort to `/dev/null` and output of perf to perf_data file.

How can I Do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can put it in parenthesis. Following command has worked for me.

```
(perf stat -x, ../bin/sort data >/dev/null) 2>perfoutput.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The "perf" command has an option to redirect output to a file directly using -o option. In your case this will be

```
perf stat -o perfoutput.dat -x, ../bin/sort data >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the way how `perf` runs the program, simply quoting the arguments may be enough:

```
perf stat -x, '../bin/sort data >/dev/null' 2>perf_data
```

Comment: when I tried this one it prints Terminated message on screen. perf_data file is not generated.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta What about putting the actual invocation into a shell-script, and `perf`ing that instead? (Of course you'll get a bit of overhead from `/bin/sh`)